# How do I talk to the drunken dwarf?

Tags: adom

I killed Holzenplozl (sp?) the crime lord. Somehow I managed to piss off the drunken dwarf. So far I've done the following.

- cast calm monster over 500 times on him
- cast scare monster 50 times
- got him scared after a companion hit him, he wouldn't Peace
- he's in the enraged state after kicking him a couple of times
- thrown a berzio potion at him to no effect
- healed him with cure light wounds a ton

Any other advice to calm him down?

Answer (score 2):

From the wiki:

There are two known approaches that may work for calming him:

- The PC can instruct a companion (ideally a weak one) to attack the drunken dwarf. This seems to make the drunken dwarf peaceful towards the PC, at least as long as the fight continues between the dwarf and the companion. It should then be possible to chat with the dwarf again. However, if the dwarf manages to kill the companion, he may once again become hostile towards the PC, so the PC should waste no time in solving the dwarf's riddle.
- The PC can attack the drunken dwarf in the hope that the dwarf will become afraid. Once the dwarf is afraid, the PC could then chat to him and offer peace. Aside from the risk of killing the dwarf, this approach is highly unreliable since the dwarf might never become afraid, even when critically injured. While the Scare Monster spell might appear to offer an alternative, this spell doesn't seem to be effective against the drunken dwarf.

Comment: Yeah none of this worked. After he killed my companion he had one line of dialog with me. But no matter how many companions I drag to him, he doesn't care anymore.

Comment: That's why it said to waste no time solving the riddle. Now you either have to try to make him afraid or restart your game and try to do the companion again.